# Derivative of a function of a matrix $f(B) = x^T(AB)^ky$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus

I have a function of the form $f(B) = x^T(AB)^ky$ where $x$ and $y$ are column matrices, $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, and $B$ is a diagonal matrix, and $k$ is an integer constant. I want to find the derivative of this function with respect to $B$. How do I go about doing something like this?

I've seen several similar questions asked here, but they all seem to have different answers and I don't know how to generalize them to fit other problems, or understand how the answers were derived. It would be greatly appreciated if I can have the names of any rules/techniques applied and/or resources from which I can learn to do this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do as in the usual case:
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{x^T(A(B+\epsilon V))^ky-x^T(AB)^ky}{\epsilon}$$ where $V$ is the "direction" in which you want to do derivatives.

Then you remember that polynomials with matrices behave like usual polynomyals a part for commutativity, so the term of order $\epsilon$ in
$(AB+\epsilon AV)^k$ is $\sum_h (AB)^h(AV)(AB)^{k-h-1}$

Thus
$$\frac{\partial f(B)}{\partial V}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{x^T((A(B+\epsilon V))^k-(AB)^k)y}{\epsilon}=x^T\big(\sum_{h=0}^{k-1}
 (AB)^h(AV)(AB)^{k-h-1}\big)y$$

Comment: Could you expand a bit on how you reached the answer from the last step? How is that limit equal to the term of order $\epsilon$ in $(AB+\epsilon AV)^k$?

Comment: $(AB+\epsilon AV)^k=(AB)^k+\epsilon T+\epsilon^2R$ where $T$ are the terms of order $\epsilon$ and $R$ are the remaining terms, those of order at least $\epsilon^2$. Therefore $(AB+\epsilon AV)^k-(AB)^k=\epsilon T+\epsilon^2R$ and so once divided by $\epsilon$ the limit is $T$.

Comment: Awesome, everything makes sense now. Thanks.